# C# Dotnet core - Issues with implementing generic DBContext in constructor

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am struggling with this coming back from a long layoff.

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875835/configuring-dbcontext-in-the-constructor-of-my-base-repository-class) regarding the configuring of a DBContext in my generic base repository. Only after a user has logged in can I then construct a connection string so I cannot register a service in startup.cs - I have to use a constructor argument to instantiate my DBContext.

I got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55876702/5750758) which I thought would address the problem however I am getting an error in the following factory class:

```
public class ContextFactory<T> : IContextFactory<T> : where T : DbContext
{
    public T CreateDbContext(string connectionString)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new T(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

The error is on the line return `new T(optionsBuilder.Options);` and is:

> Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not
>   have the new() constraint

Comment: even if you add `new()` constraint you end  up with `'T': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type`. You were given invalid code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you add `new()` constraint, you will end up with the following error

> 'T': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type.

You were given invalid code.

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

Reference [new constraint (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

Another option to consider could be to use [Activator.CreateInstance (Type, Object[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___).

Given

```
public interface IContextFactory<TContext> where TContext : DbContext {
    TContext Create(string connectionString);
}
```

You would implement it as follows

```
public class ContextFactory<TContext> : IContextFactory<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext {

    public TContext Create(string connectionString) {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

This could be refactored further to separate concerns

```
public class ContextFactory<TContext> : IContextFactory<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext {

    public TContext Create(DbContextOptions<TContext> options) {
        return (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), options);
    }
}
```

so that the builder will become the responsibility of where the factory is being used.

```
var connection = @"....";
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);

//Assuming factory is `IContextFactory<BloggingContext>`    
using (var context = factory.Create(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
   // do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**

The factory can be registered as open generics in `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IContextFactory<>), typeof(ContextFactory<>));
```

Comment: I think I need to register the factory in startup as a singleton - if so how?

Comment: @Nkosi: Thanks for spotting the mistake in the code that I provided to answer Simon's original question. I have edited the answer to show how the factory can be registered as open generics.

Comment: @si2030 please have a look at the updated answer to the original question.

Comment: Thank you. However, this code did not work in my project.     I coded it this way                     services.AddTransient(typeof(DatabaseContextFactory));       and it worked in my project