# EF core Using a generic factory to register a DB context

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am out to sea with this.

I received this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55876702/5750758) which was corrected [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55886589/5750758) by Nkosi.. however whilst it indicated how to rewrite the factory I am not up to the task of implementing it.. I need some gaps filled in.

As I understand it, this is what I need to do..

define the interface:

```
public interface IContextFactory<TContext> where TContext : DbContext 
{
    TContext Create(string connectionString);
}
```

Create the factory:

```
public class ContextFactory<TContext> : IContextFactory<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public TContext Create(DbContextOptions<TContext> options)
    {
        return (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), options);
    }
}
```

register the factory as a singleton in startup.

This is what I did and I dont know if this is correct?

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IContextFactory<>), typeof(ContextFactory<>));
```

Next how the heck do I use this factory?

In the first answer, it was suggested I use this:

```
public class EntityBaseRepository<T> : IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
{
    private JobsLedgerAPIContext _context;

    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public EntityBaseRepository(IContextFactory<JobsLedgerAPIContext> factory)
    {
        _context = factory.CreateDbContext(ConnectionString);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual int Count()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Count();
    }
}
```

Nkosi identified that you cannot have the constraint "new()" and a parameterized constructor. He rewrote it. How do I change the above code to reflect the fact the factory now does not have a parameterized constructor but still take in the connection string given Nkosi's factory?

ClientRepository inherits the above.

```
public class ClientRepository : EntityBaseRepository<Client>, IClientRepository
{
    private new JobsLedgerAPIContext _context;

    public ClientRepository(JobsLedgerAPIContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

Does this constructor need to be changed.

And finally how do I Inject the ClientRepository now that I have to supply a connection string?

Comment: I think you should ignore answers to all your previous questions and start over. There is no need to modify the services / repositories having `LobsLedgerAPIContext` dependency. What you need is to make that context dependent of some service providing the information about the current logged in user - similar to `AppTenant` from [ASP.NET Core Multi-tenancy: Data Isolation with Entity Framework](https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-multi-tenancy-data-isolation-with-entity-framework)

Comment: Ivan's suggestion is sound and would really simplify the design that was originally suggested to you. As part of your auth process you could add the connection string as a claim on the current user principle. From there you can inject details into the context that will use it in `OnConfiguring` just like in the linked  article.

Comment: The answer I provided you was just to fix the syntax issues in the suggested answer you got. I personally would not have gone with the design as it abstracts for abstraction sake and over complicates tings unnecessarily.

Comment: This appears to be a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @si2030 could you solve this problem. now, ıhave a problem like it :( if you could solve your problem, can you help me ?