# EF Dotnet Core - Setting connection string after solution running

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866647/dotnet-core-setting-the-connection-string-after-startup-has-run) because I wanted to find out how to create a DbContext where you only know the connection string after a user has been authenticated (connection string part of the user detail in a catalog database). My problem was that I cant set this in startup service as I have to wait for the user to log in.

I [got an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55866882/5750758) that suggested This:

```
    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=JobsLedgerDB;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);

    using (var context = new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
    {
      // do stuff
    }
```

Camilo Terevinto commented on this saying that this is a really terrible suggestion saying:

> Using AddDbContext, EF Core uses a factory behind to decide when new
>   instances are created

I have noted that this option (answer) is actually in the [EF Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) under "Constructor Argument".

If its in the docs and appears to be the only way I can run create a connection after a user logs in is it OK? Is there a better way? Are there things I need to be aware of etc.. Wondering if someone can elaborate on Camilo's comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DotNet Core setting the connection string after startup has run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866647/dotnet-core-setting-the-connection-string-after-startup-has-run)

Comment: Added an extra answer in the original question. You could have asked Camilo Terevinto for an explanation there as well.

Comment: Lol sorry, I just now realized you where the author of that question as well...