# How can I add a dbContext after Startup in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am using .Net Core, using the built-in dependency injection.  In my login screen, I need the user to also choose a departmental database - we have different databases with the same structure to use the same application with different data.  However, I can't figure out how to add/modify the dbContext that late.  Startup.cs has the DI, but I don't know which connection string to read from the config until the user has chosen the department.  It is a small database, and the company is not concerned about the management of the duplicate databases.

How can I add the service late

```
services.AddDbContext<my_accountingContext>(options =>
options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CorrectDepartmentConfig")));
```

when I actually know what CorrectDepartmentConfig is?

Or, if that can't be done, how can I do a smelly change of the my_accountingContext after Startup.cs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DotNet Core setting the connection string after startup has run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866647/dotnet-core-setting-the-connection-string-after-startup-has-run)

Comment: The answer by @PeterBons works with a different overload - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an implementation factory overload of `IServiceCollection` in `ConfigureServices` method form `Startup` class:

```
//First register a custom made db context provider
services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContextFactory>();
//Then use implementation factory to get the one you need
services.AddTransient(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContextFactory>().CreateApplicationDbContext());
```

The implementation of `CreateApplicationDbContext` depends on your specific needs, but a base implementation should look like the following:

```
public ApplicationDbContext CreateApplicationDbContext(){
  //TODO Something clever to create correct ApplicationDbContext with ConnectionString you need.
}
```

After this implementation, you can inject the correct `ApplicationDbContext` in your controller, action...

```
public MyController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}

public IActionResult([FromServices] ApplicationDbContext dbContext){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the connection string from inside the protected OnConfiguring method. You can get access to the IConfiguration instance from there (the DbContext class has a service locator, Instance property), retrieve the connection string, and then call UseMySql extension method with the appropriate connection.

Something like this:

```
protected virtual void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    var configuration = (this as IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>).GetService<IConfiguration>();
    var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("<name>");
    builder.UseMySql(connectionString);
    base.OnConfiguring(builder);
}
```

For the strongly-typed version of GetService do not forget to reference namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

Comment: This looks like it will work, thanks.  But I'm having trouble with this.Instance.GetService - "'my_accountingContext' does not contain a definition for 'Instance' and no accessible extension method 'Instance' accepting a first argument of type 'rev_accountingContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".  I have the using and the assembly reference for DependencyInjection.

Comment: See my edit. The Instance property comes from IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>.

Comment: Thank you.  Now, when attempting to execute "var configuration = ...", it complains that I'm using something while I'm attempting to configure it.  'An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'  

What did I do wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, but there is a problem with my solution, as you just noticed. I think that the best way would be to pass an instance of IConfiguration to the DbContext-derived class through a factory method, as in the solution described below, and then store it and use it on the OnConfiguring method, rather than accessing the Instance property.